# image files corrupt with websocket file transfer

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, blob, html5-filesystem

I am using websockets for file transfer, while i am downloading a file i am recieving the data as it is, but when I open an image file it was corrupted. Data files are downloading fine, the code goes as follows.

```
try {
    fileEntry = fs.root.getFile(filename, { create : creat_file });
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(data.data.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
        byteArray[i] = data.data.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;
    }
    BlobBuilderObj = new WebKitBlobBuilder();
    BlobBuilderObj.append(byteArray.buffer);
    if (!writer) {
        writer = fileEntry.createWriter();
        pos = 0;
    }
    //self.postMessage(writer.position);
    writer.seek(pos);
    writer.write(BlobBuilderObj.getBlob());
    pos += 4096;
    }
catch (e) {
    errorHandler(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are reading data from a WebSocket as a string, converting it to a Blob, and then writing this to a file.

If you have control of the WebSocket server then the best thing would be to send the data as binary frames instead of UTF-8 text data. If you can get the server to send the data as binary frames then you can just tell the WebSocket to deliver the data as Blobs:

```
ws.binaryType = "blob";
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
    if (event.data instanceof Blob) {
        // event.data is a Blob
    } else {
        // event.data is a string
    }
}
```

If that is not an option and you can only send text frames from the server, then you will need to encode the binary data to text before sending it from the server and then decode the text on the other end. If you try and send binary data directly as text frames over WebSockets then doing `charCodeAt(x) && 0xff` will result in corrupt data.

For example you could base64 encode the data at the server and then base64 decode the data in the client:

```
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
    raw = window.atob(event.data);
}
```

**Update**:

There is a very well performing pure Javascript base64 decode/encode contained in [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify). It decodes to an an array of numbers from 0-255 but could be easily modified to return a string instead if that is what you require (Disclaimer: I made websockify).

Comment: sorry!,Here I have a problem I am doing it in worker so no btoa atob functions allowed. anyway thanks for your response

Comment: According to the W3C (http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#apis-available-to-workers) and to Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Worker/Functions_available_to_workers) the base64 functions should be available to Web Workers (along with timing functions).

Comment: But I am building my app only for chrome.

Comment: @rajuk, the web workers specification requires base64 support. If it's missing then that's a bug and you should file a webkit bug: http://www.webkit.org/quality/reporting.html

Comment: @rajuk: I added an update inline referring to websockify which contains a very fast pure Javascript base64 encode/decode implementation.

Comment: sorry I can't understand the documentation and I dont have that much time to read it simply provide a polyfill to do solve this.